# Add Widget to bottom in the Card

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm looking for a way to set a Widget in the bottom of a Card, I don't know if that's the Widget that I have to use, but, the code that I have is the following:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
      primary: true,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
      childAspectRatio: 1.5,
      crossAxisCount: 1,
        children: <Widget>[
 Card(
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                const ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.album),
                  title: const Text('The Enchanted Nightingale'),
                  subtitle: const Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
                ),
                new ButtonTheme.bar( // make buttons use the appropriate styles for cards
                  child: new ButtonBar(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new FlatButton(
                        child: const Text('BUY TICKETS'),
                        onPressed: () { /* ... */ },
                      ),
                      new FlatButton(
                        child: const Text('LISTEN'),
                        onPressed: () { /* ... */ },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ]
    );
  }
```

So, I want to add something like bottom: Text('I am the bottom')

This is what I want, a Widget in the bottom and add children inside it.
[image: I want to add a bar or a Widget in the bottom]
I'll appreciate some help.

Comment: do you have a image about what do you want?

Comment: let me create one

Comment: I just edited the post with the image

Comment: Just one more suggestion. Not related to your problem. `GirdView with crossAxisCount = 1` is equal to `ListView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution, using a Scaffold and consuming its own bottomNavigationBar.

```
Card(
        child: Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: Text('This is my text'),
          body: new Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              const ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.album),
                title: const Text('The Enchanted Nightingale'),
                subtitle: const Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
              ),
              new ButtonTheme.bar( // make buttons use the appropriate styles for cards
                child: new ButtonBar(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new FlatButton(
                      child: const Text('BUY TICKETS'),
                      onPressed: () { /* ... */ },
                    ),
                    new FlatButton(
                      child: const Text('LISTEN'),
                      onPressed: () { /* ... */ },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      )
```

Comment: I thought that you wanted your widget as an Item for a List , otherwise scaffold bottomNavigationBar is the best option.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `Expanded` widget wrapping your `ListTile`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Container(
            child: GridView.count(
                primary: true,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                childAspectRatio: 1.5,
                crossAxisCount: 1,
                children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: const ListTile(
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.album),
                    title: const Text('The Enchanted Nightingale'),
                    subtitle: const Text(
                        'Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: new ButtonBar(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new FlatButton(
                        child: const Text('BUY TICKETS'),
                        onPressed: () {/* ... */},
                      ),
                      new FlatButton(
                        child: const Text('LISTEN'),
                        onPressed: () {/* ... */},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ])));
```

I just add a container with a custom color to see the bottom part.